# Laratrust is not saving data to database with Jetstream and Laravel 10

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-jetstream, laratrust

I am using **Laravel 10** and **Jetstream authentication** for my project. I am trying to use the **Laratrust** for multi-authentication and roles. I have run all the commands of **Laratrust** but I am unable to understand where to add this `$user->addRole($admin);` line of code.
I have registered for new users but the user roles aren't saving in the database.

Can anyone help me out to solve this problem?

Comment: > `but I am unable to understand where to add this "$user->addRole($admin);`  <<<=== you can do it in the Seeder. Create that $admin role and apply it to that created $user